# Using DWT CYCCNT on STM32H7 for step by step debugging

Tags: arm, stm32

I'm using DWT_CYCCNT on a STM32H7 to count clock cycle.

Software is bare-metal, STM32H7 is runnning @ 400MHz, code is executing from internal AXI-SRAM, no usage of low-power modes or exception during the test case.

I set up the DWT counter by enabling DWT_CTRL.CYCCNTENA.

Then if I execute the software step by step, every asm instruction iterates the DWT_CYCCNT of 20 clock cycles.

Does that mean that clock cycle counting does not work in step by step execution ?

Comment: it counts clock cycles not instructions, instructions can/do take more than one clock.

Comment: particularly running at 400mhz.

Comment: Yes of course I Know. Still , 20 cycles per instructions seems a lot

Comment: I measured the nb of cycle of a fonction,  first executing step by step,  then executing without break,  the results are completely different

Comment: I would not necessarily expect single step and free running to match.

Comment: provide a complete minimal example please, cannot help otherwise (other than to say no real surprises yet).

Comment: you are likely in part measuring the debugger.